# How to create Java GUI program for complex mathematical equations

Tags: java, geometry, trigonometry

I am going through Java AWT & Swings and came to know on how to create the basic GUI elements and I was able to work on some programs with it. But when I am trying to understand how to create Graphs for some complex mathematical equations then I was not able to find some documentation or any examples.

For example, in this post - [How to solve the trigonometric equation cos(πθ/β)−cos(2πθ/β)=0?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/887658/how-to-solve-the-trigonometric-equation-cos-pi-theta-beta-cos2-pi-thet?newreg=5177b75324ea452498b4535895dd0d5b)

the user has given some complex equation and also shown how the graphs looks like.

But how can we write a Java program for this equation that generates the graph GUI as output?

Can someone please point me to some documentation or links so that I can understand how to achieve this in Java?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar question on this, go through these links to understand how to create the GUI in Java:

[Java Swing GUI for equation 5((θ/β) - cos(2πθ/β))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28075431/java-swing-gui-for-equation-5%CE%B8-%CE%B2-cos2%CF%80%CE%B8-%CE%B2)

[Java Swing GUI for equation 5((θ/β) - cos(2πθ/β)) - to draw continuous graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28077216/java-swing-gui-for-equation-5%CE%B8-%CE%B2-cos2%CF%80%CE%B8-%CE%B2-to-draw-continuous-graph)